# In my app, I set up that two textboxes save their last entry. However, they store the same data, how can I resolve it?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have the following code:

```
Textbox1.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.textbox;
Textbox2.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.textbox;
```

....

```
Properties.Settings.Default.textbox = Textbox1.Text;
Properties.Settings.Default.textbox = Textbox2.Text;
```

Expectation:
To have those textfields to store latest data upon restart.

Reality:
They do actually store latest data, but they all store the same entry that is written in Textbox1.

How can I resolve it? I am not a developer, but now I need to create a small tool and I am stuck with it. Thanks for any help, really appreciated!

Comment: Have two separate properties  instead of one?

Comment: @rene Thank you very much! I suspect this might be the solution, however, I am not sure how to do that. Could you please show me an example how to do that? Thank you in advance! Have a great day!

Comment: No, but instead I looked it up for you in the MSDN docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx